# How to update QGraphicsScene in a QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a simple Mandlebrot viewer in Qt, I have a Mainwindow with a QGraphicsScene in it, I generate the QImage with the picture and then I have some buttons that I'd like to use to navigate the image (Move, zoom, etc.)

I can get the initial image to appear, however I'm not sure how to tell it to rerender after I've changed any of the coordinates.
For the life of me I can't work out how to refresh the QMainWindow, or alternatively remove the QGraphicsScene from the MainWindow and make a call to render it.

```
QImage renderImage(//loads in global variables)
{
    //calculates the image and returns a QImage
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene *graphic = new QGraphicsScene( this );
    graphic->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(renderImage()));
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(graphic);

}

void MainWindow::on_Left_clicked()
{
    // Changes global variables and try to rerender the scene.

    update(); //does nothing
}
```

---

UPDATE: Solved!
Thank you so much goug, that helped a lot.  I'm new to Qt, so couldn't work out where the loop was that would update things. I added the code you suggested and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene *graphic = new QGraphicsScene( this );
    pixmap_item = graphic->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(renderImage()));
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(graphic);

}

void MainWindow::on_Left_clicked()
{
    // Changes global variables and try to rerender the scene.
    centerR -= 0.1;
    pixmap_item->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(renderImage()));
}
```

Comment: He has a QGraphicsView. It's in the UI definition and properly set up in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show any code that changes any coordinates, or anything for that matter. For the built-in graphics items such as `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, which is what you create by call `addPixmap`, you generally don't have to force anything. Those objects repaint themselves as needed when you change something via their member functions.

I suspect that where you're going wrong is that you may be believing that there's a connection between the pixmap and the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` that you created in the constructor. There isn't; so if it's the pixmap that you're changing, then you need to reapply that pixmap to the pixmap item. You'll need a new member in your class to track:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmap_item_;
```

And change your constructor code to:

```
pixmap_item_ = graphic->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(renderImage()));
```

Then whenever you've updated your pixmap, reapply that pixmap to the graphics item you've created in the constructor:

```
pixmap_item_->setPixmap (QPixmap::fromImage(renderImage()));
```

The `setPixmap` call will trigger the pixmap item to repaint itself; you don't have to call `update()` separately. If this isn't the issue, then we need to see more of your code.